# Change Duration of DoubleAnimation Control by Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I'm trying to change duration of DoubleAnimation control by Slider's value but it does not get effect. I don't know why?

Here's my code:

XAML:

```
<Border.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
       <BeginStoryboard>
           <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="borUpperTranslate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
               <DoubleAnimation Name="dbaUpperTranslate" From="418" To="230" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
       </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
```

C#:

```
 private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            Slider sl = sender as Slider;
            dbaUpperTranslate.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sl.Value));
        }
```

Any help would be appreciate! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RepeatBehavior="Forever"` set to `True`, so this animation will run forever which gets initiated with duration set to 0:0:1.

If you remove `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` and hook on an event say `MouseLeftButtonDown`, it works as expected.

---

However, in case you want to update it with `RepeatBehavior="Forever"`, you need to `stop animation first, set duration and than restart animation`.

Set name on storyBoard:

```
<Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="borUpperTranslate"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Name="storyboard">
```

And in handler:

```
Slider sl = sender as Slider;
storyboard.Stop();
dbaUpperTranslate.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sl.Value));
storyboard.Begin();
```

Moreover, if you don't want jerky look, you should consider removing `From` attribute, so it will resume from where it left before stopping animation.

Comment: Awesome! I did it. Thank you so much Mr Rohit Vats.